# How to create an object form a string in actionscript 3.0 (as3)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

How can I create a dynamic object from a string?

Here is my current code with incorrect results:

```
var s1:String = '{x:200, y:400}';
var o1:Object = Object(s1);

trace(o1); // result = {x:200, y:400}
trace(o1.x) // result = ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property x not found on String and there is no default value.
trace(o1.y) // result = ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property x not found on String and there is no default value.
```

I would like the previous code to output the following:

```
trace(o1); // result = [object Object]
trace(o1.x); // result = 200
trace(o1.y); // result = 400
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

[as3corelib](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/) contains a JSON parser that would do this for you. Make sure you study the [issues list](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/issues/list) as there have been no new releases of this library and there are plenty of bugs in it, that are mostly addressed in the issues list.

Comment: I was just about to answer the same thing :)    to solve the specific problem you'll be using the JSON class in that lib: `JSON.decode(str)` and `JSON.encode(obj)` to go the other way.

Comment: About the bugs, there are people fixing it. See: http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/source/list . You just need to check out from the SVN.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is the best way, but:

```
var serializedObject:String = '{x:200,y:400}'
var object:Object = new Object()

var contentWithoutBraces:String = serializedObject.substr(serializedObject.indexOf('{') + 1)
contentWithoutBraces = contentWithoutBraces.substr(0, contentWithoutBraces.lastIndexOf('}'))

var propertiesArray:Array = contentWithoutBraces.split(',')

for (var i:uint = 0; i < propertiesArray.length; i++)
{
    var objectProperty:Array = propertiesArray[i].split(':')

    var propertyName:String = trim(objectProperty[0])
    var propertyValue:String = trim(objectProperty[1])

    object[propertyName] = Object(propertyValue)
}

trace(object)
trace(object.x)
trace(object.y)
```

This will do what you want.

You can do this in a recursive manner so if the object contains other objects also are converted ;)

PS: I don't add the trim function, but this function recieve a String and returns a new String without spaces at the beginning or at the end of the String.

Answer (score 3):

For the record, the JSON parser won't parse the string in the example, since JSON requires quotes around member names. So the string:

```
var s1:String = '{x:200, y:400}';
```

... would instead have to be:

```
var s1:String = '{"x":200, "y":400}';
```

It can be a bit confusing that object notation, like {x:200, y:400}, that is valid in both ActionScript and JavaScript is not valid JSON, but if I remember it right, the quotes around member names are necessary to avoid possible conflicts with reserved words.

http://simonwillison.net/2006/Oct/11/json/

Answer (score 1):

The newer versions of Flash Player contains in the top level the JSON class, read the doc:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html